# Cannot find out way to minify ejs file in express website scaffoled through express generator

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, minify

I am unable to find out a way to minify ejs file in my express site generated through an express generator. It contains lots of dynamic code including javascript like functions, if-else blocks, and for loops. I want to minify the HTML to optimize a website.  But I cannot find out a way anywhere. Has someone accomplished this?